# How to pull candidates with symbol "|" uses egrep

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have a slight tricky issue, and hope finding life savior here.

```
FileA:
A|AA
A|+AB
A|-AC

Expected outcome:
A|+AA
A|-AB
```

I'm trying to grep all pattern with "|+" & "|-". 
All the moment I managed to grep by two separate liners.

```
grep "|+" FileA > output
grep "|-" FileA >> output
```

Is there's a way I can achieve the same uses **egrep**.
Struggling with "|" as I need it for two interpretations, one is multiple conditions, another is symbol "|".

Comment: for future reference, learn escaping metacharacters with ``\``... so, with BRE, `grep '|+\||-'` and with egrep or ERE, `grep -E '\|\+|\|-'`

Comment: @Sundeep, short and precise explanation.
Now I deeply understand (when/when's not) to escape '|' when uses grep/egrep.
This is indeed useful!

Answer (score 1):

All you needed was a character class:

```
grep '|[+-]' FileA
A|+AB
A|-AC
```

Comment: Thanks Savior tink! Love the trick that you made! Why can't I think of this?!